# Load web activity output into a SQL table using Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have some data in my SQL table. I have to pass the data in certain columns to a webservice and capture the output of the webservice in some other columns of the same table (Basically the webservice is designed to cleanse my data). I tried using lookup activity and pass the output of the columns in the body of the http request as dynamic content, but the lookup activity does fetch only 5k rows. Is there a way to fetch all the rows and update the target columns based on the webservice call output ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a copy activity where you create HTTP Linked Service for the source.

The sink can be a staging table in the SQL database, and you can create a stored procedure for updating existing table.

It is also possible to use a stored procedure for sink table. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57256158/azure-data-factory-copy-data-activity-sql-sink-stored-procedure-and-table-typed)

This way is "more" complicated, so I recommend staging table + stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Ruben. I've got one more query. The body of my HTTP request is dynamic and a lookup activity is supplying this dynamic body. Since lookup fetch one row at a time and each row is looped inside a for each activity. Is there a way to skip this For Each loop and directly load the table with any other service ?